# In Excel:convert or split time format

Tags: microsoft-excel

in Excel, in one column I have "time" by format of " 1:00 A.M to 1:59 A.M" and trying to convert it to the format of " 1:00 A.M". How can I do this with a formula, cause I have tried "delimited" but i cannot apply it for thousands of rows.
I have "1:00 am to 1:59 am"
I want to have "1:00 am"

Comment: I'm sure there are more complicated solutions that are more exact, but I like the 80/20 rule- fix 80% the easy way and worry about 20% manually. If this were in cell B2, I'll enter into C2 `=LEFT(B2,5)`.

Comment: Excel would see the value of "1:00 A.M to 1:59 A.M" as a string.  You would not be converting an actual date/time.  You are simply truncating everything beyond the first time in the string as in jatuttle0's example.

Comment: Assuming there is one space between time & AM/PM and there is no dot between AM/PM (It's not like A.M. or P.M.)  use a formula =LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,1)+2). This may normally return text

Comment: all will depend on how your data is formatted, as the above comments stay. Maybe looking for " to " will give you a more stable result.

Comment: I have 1:00 am, but I want 1:00 am? I have apple, but I want apple? Your question needs a little work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your time is in c1 then there are 3 ways of doing this Enter in D1

1. +INT(24*c1)/24  Just set the cell format to time in the format you want.
2. =+SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(C1,"HH: AM/PM"),":",":00")
3. =C1 and use a custom format of hh:"00" AM/PM
   to display it as you wish

What is going on is time is a number format where 1 = 1 day or 24 hours. The first one use this with an int to truncate it to the hour.

The second one use Text to convert the time to text and then substitute to get the format correct.

The last just uses a custom format to display it like was desired. (to the hour only)